# Accessory Development Kit hardware compatibility

Tags: android, arduino, adk, android-hardware

I am new to Accessory Development. If I was to build a custom hardware component what should it support in order to be able to communicate with Android applications via USB?

I am doing a research for a project and the clients are hardware manufacturer and want to know what should their hardware component support(in terms of communication protocols) in order to be able to commnicate with Android devices. I found that Arduino microcontrollers are an example for such components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ADK documentation](http://source.android.com/accessories/custom.html) is the place to look for the specs, which are too long to include here. The [ArduinoBoardADK](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardADK) implements the protocol, using a MAX3421e to handle the USB host side. The other Arduino boards don't have USB host capability, so are not suitable.

Comment: Thanks. The other thing is that the android device will not use the standard micro usb port. It will not be a 'phone' but a TV attached device like Minix devices. It should use standard USB port not micro usb. Do you think this would make a difference?

Answer (score -1):

Arduino microcontrollers communicate using standard serial comms over the USB port.
http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/lesson4.html

I don't believe Android devices works in the same way.

Comment: Some android devices do support serial communication over USB. Galaxy S4 for example.